# Regular expression in html to create same pattern

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create multiple boxes with background and border with same pattern, So I just have to create boxes nth time or is there any formula which use that regular expression and repeat the same code in html.I want to append child with parent class box.

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid gray;background-color: black;width: 10px;height: 10px "></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: You can do with the help of `javascript` but not purely HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by regex to repeat HTML? You can use JavaScript to repeatedly insert HTML into the DOM

```js
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.classList.add("boxDiv");
const HTML = Array.from(Array(10).keys()).map(i => div.cloneNode().outerHTML).join("")
document.querySelector(".box").innerHTML += HTML
```

```css
.boxDiv { border: 1px solid gray;background-color: black;width: 10px;height: 10px }
```

```html
<div class="box">
</div>
```

Comment: i want to append child with div class="box"; it append at the end of body